# Moving using 301 in htaccess using GET variables

Tags: .htaccess

What am I doing wrong? 
I have

```
http://www.site.com/shop/viewmy/?ASIN=234FhK3
http://www.site.com/shop/viewmy/?ASIN=423ZH3
```

Trying to convert to

```
http://www.site.com/shopping/234FhK3/moved
http://www.site.com/shopping/423ZH3/moved
```

I'm going to change the "moved" part with an internal redirect after I get some info about the product 234FhK3 , a variable that changes.

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ASIN=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(shopping/)/?$ $1.(/moved)? [L,R=301,NC]
```

I'm not too good with htaccess rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ASIN=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/viewmy/$ /shopping/%1/moved/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Wow.. I spent over an hour and a half trying and researching.. you got it on first go.. thank you!

Comment: By the way [L,R=301,NC] this part "R=301" is correct to use in this way right? since I'm trying to do a 301 redirect. Your redirect works, just making sure it's a 301 Permanent Redirect

Comment: I'm glad if that helped you. Yes, 301 flag means that link will be redirected to new address with "301 Moved permanently" code.

Comment: I would make it a bit more specific, instead of matching any url, with a ASIN get-variable. To do this use `... RewriteRule ^shop/viewmy/$ /shopping/%1/moved/? [L,R=301,NC]` instead. Also; don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gerben! I actually needed your provided rule for another section with a different variable such as ID which could be "anything", came handy. The ASIN is fine by me since they're only used for shopping stuff, thus in only one part of the site.